# Can't see the forks of a project on GitHub when "Too many forks to display" is shown

Tags: github

When I click on a project with a lot of forks, I see the following message:

> Couldn't load network graph.
>
> Too many forks to display.

Example: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/network

What to do when this is displayed? How can I see the forks of a project when it's hosted on GitHub and there are too many to list according to the network graph?

Answer (score 21):

**Update 02 March 2021**

The app below is no longer available and the domain redirects to some spam site.
It served me well for 5 years.

**Original answer:**

I just stumbled across an app called Stargazers forks (link removed) which lets you see all the forked versions of a repo regardless of how many forks there are. You can sort by number of issues, stars, or last updated.

Comment: Very useful, thanks! I use the [Lovely forks](https://github.com/musically-ut/lovely-forks) browser extension to see the one most popular fork when I visit a repo, but yannick's site is good for browsing the complete list.

Answer (score 7):

If GitHub won't show you the network graph because there are too many forks, try the Members tab instead.

You may still get the following warning:

> Woah, this network is huge! We're showing only some of this network's repositories.

but at least you'll be able to see some of the forks.

Comment: Alright, but this seems to be a limitation of github somehow i.e. to see "some of the forks" is not the same as seeing them all :) Up-voting for the recommendation, though.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use GitHub API ( https://developer.github.com/v3 ) and parse JSON in any language to filter data ( only names and links to forks )

https://api.github.com/repos/odoo/odoo/forks

In response headers you can find next pages

```
Link:"<https://api.github.com/repositories/19745004/forks?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/19745004/forks?page=122>; rel="last""
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this web to find the forks of a GitHub project. Hope it helps!
https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html

Edit:
Just open this [URL](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html) and paste there the GitHub repo URL from which you want to see the active forks. It is very straight forward.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).